# How to pass/make an object/variable accessible inside a callback function which is called by a third party library?

Tags: c++, callback, global-variables, global-object

How to make `globalObject` accessible by `callbackFunction`?

I am using a third party library `library.h` which has a method `libraryFunction`. The output of `libraryFunction` is a `libraryFunctionOutput` which is passed into the callback function `callbackFunction`.

How to pass another object (e.g. `globalObject`) for use inside the callback function `callbackFunction`?

Unfortunately the third party library is compiled so I cannot make any changes to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

int callbackFunction(int libraryFunctionOutput):
    printf("%s, %d", libraryFunctionOutput, globalObject);
    return 1;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int globalObject = 0;
   libraryFunction(callbackFunction);
}
```

In the documentation, the function is shown as:

```
int __stdcall libraryFunction(const char*    filename,
                              unsigned int   flags,
                              int            userID,
                              MathrelCallback callbackFunction);
```

The `MathrelCallback` struct is defined as the following:

```
struct MathrelCallback {MathrelHeader header;
                        MathrelInfo   data;
                        unsigned int Type;
};
```

Comment: What is the signature of `libraryFunction` ? If it accepts lambda the answer will be trivial. Don't know if it is possible if it only accepts function pointers except by copying `globalObject` in a global variable.

Comment: Most C-style APIs also pass a context pointer. You should use that for context.

Comment: @Franck I've added how the library looks like in the documentation. I don't think it does accept lambda. I am happy with a globalObject in a global variable as it is a relatively small application. 


@krzaq Unfortunately no other contextual arguments can be passed inside `libraryFunction` other then which callback function to use.

Comment: Can you post the definition of MathrelCallback? I guess it's just a plain function pointer, but who knows...

Comment: @Horstling Updated the post to add `MathrelCallback` definition.

Comment: Ok thats definitely not a plain callback. Hard to say what you can do with that without documentation.

Comment: I'll speak to the provider on Monday, your global variable/object solution worked great! It was a bit tricky as I had to use another third party's custom object. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the library really takes a function pointer (not a generalized Callable like std::function) and does not offer the ability to pass a context or user pointer to your callback, you have to make your global object global (with all its drawbacks):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "library.h"

static int globalObject = 0;

int callbackFunction(int libraryFunctionOutput)
{
    printf("%s, %d", libraryFunctionOutput, globalObject);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   libraryFunction(callbackFunction);
}
```

Comment: Would this compile?  I'm trying to make a small example work and I must be missing something. The `:` looks out of place?

Comment: Try changing `int main(int argcm char* argv[])` to `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`.

Comment: Oh sry, just copied and edited the original code, didn't even notice the errors.